# Neukirch, Proposition 2.11

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading Neukirch's *Algebraic Number Theory*, and I do not understand the following step in the proof of Proposition 2.11.

The proof can be found in [this imgur album](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8D1pQ.jpg), but only the very end confuses me.

The step that confuses me is on one of the last lines. He writes M as a product of two $n' \times n'$ matrices, each of whose entries is an $n \times n$ matrix. He then says, "By changing indices the second matrix may be transformed to look like the first one," and writes,
$$\det(M)^2 = \det(Q)^{2n'} \det((\sigma_{\ell}^{'}\omega_j^{'}))^{2n}.$$

I understand the $\det(Q)^{2n'}$ term, but I do not understand where the $\det((\sigma_{\ell}^{'}\omega_j^{'}))^{2n}$ comes from or what he means by "changing indices". It seems to me that because the second matrix is $n' \times n'$ as well, you would except an exponent of $2n'$, rather than $2n$. But I'm not sure how he's calculating it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll give an example to show what he's on about. Consider the matrix
$$\pmatrix{a&0&0&b&0&0\\0&a&0&0&b&0\\0&0&a&0&0&b\\c&0&0&d&0&0\\0&c&0&0&d&0\\0&0&c&0&0&d}.$$
By applying a permutation of rows, and the corresponding permutation of columns, this transforms into
$$\pmatrix{a&b&0&0&0&0\\c&d&0&0&0&0\\0&0&a&b&0&0\\0&0&c&d&0&0\\0&0&0&0&a&b\\0&0&0&0&c&d}$$
and so has the same determinant as this new matrix, viz.,
$\det\pmatrix{a & b\\c & d}^3$.

Comment: Thanks! That immediately clarifies why it's $2n$ and not $2n'$ in the exponent.

Comment: Apparently one can accept an answer without upvoting it. People are strange.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer users with less than 15 of reputation can't upvote.

Comment: Indeed, I attempted to upvote it, but it didn't display, as I had just made this account at the time.